# Maven solrj issue

Tags: spring, maven, solr

I can run my app and there's no problem at all but when i'm adding

```
<dependency>     
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

to my pom file it throws:

```
15:59:18,172 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-3) Context initialization failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: eu.combc.webuzu.configuration.SecurityConfig
```

any idea what's going on?

Comment: could you try current version 1.3.0.RELEASE?

Comment: checked all versions, still got the same error

Comment: eu.combc.webuzu.configuration.SecurityConfig is it your class? Could you update your question with spring context

Answer (score 0):

check with this :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
    <version>4.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Well, it's not the same : )